# How to pass the button value into my onclick event function?

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="button" value="mybutton1" onclick="dosomething()">test
```

The dosomething function evoked when to click the button,how can pass the value of the button `mybutton1` into dosomething function as it's parameter ？

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can pass the value to the function using `this.value`, where `this` points to the button

```
<input type="button" value="mybutton1" onclick="dosomething(this.value)">
```

And then access that value in the function

```
function dosomething(val){
  console.log(val);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you can take a look at closure in JavaScript.
Here is a working solution:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="button">Button 0</p>
        <p class="button">Button 1</p>
        <p class="button">Button 2</p>
        <script>
            var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
            for (var i=0 ; i < buttons.length ; i++){
              (function(index){
                buttons[index].onclick = function(){
                  alert("I am button " + index);
                };
              })(i)
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: NOTE: The buttons must exist at the time the script is executed. Therefore, place the script in the html file *below* (after) the buttons (as shown in this answer), or inside a "document ready" function.

Comment: If use **jquery**, access to the element clicked on is simply `$(this)`. For example: `$( ".button" ).on( "click", function() { alert("I am a button with value " + $(this).attr('value')`); }` defines a click function that accesses an attributte named `value` on the clicked button. That is, if each button definition is something like: `<p class="button" value="my value here">Button 0</p>`. With jquery, don't need a closure, nor an explicit array of buttons.

Answer (score 6):

You can pass the element into the function `<input type="button" value="mybutton1" onclick="dosomething(this)">test` by passing this. Then in the function you can access the value like this:

```
function dosomething(element) {
  console.log(element.value);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do like this.

```
<input type="button" value="mybutton1" onclick="dosomething(this)">

function dosomething(element){
    alert("value is "+element.value); //you can print any value like id,class,value,innerHTML etc.
};
```

Comment: could you tell me how to get the element.value?
//you can print any value like id,class,value,innerHTML etc.
how can print that?

Comment: I didnt understand your question. Did you mean console.log of element?? Here element means event...

Comment: oh no, I actually want to know how to get this element value. I did that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can get value by using id for that element in onclick function

```
function dosomething(){
     var buttonValue = document.getElementById('buttonId').value;
}
```