# Is it possible to pass the value of an 'id' attribute into a function passed in the onClick attribute in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm trying to build a calculator.

In all of the buttons representing numbers, I'm trying to convert the 'id' (that contains a String, such as "nine") into a number by using methods in the component. But I can't figure out how to pass the value of the id attribute as a parameter for a function passed to the "onClick" attribute.

Example:

`<button className={c + 'secondary col'} id="seven" onClick={() => this.inputNumber(this.id)}>7</button>`

Is there a way to do it? **this.id** doesn't seem to refer to the attribute I've set in the same line.

Here's the whole (unfinished) component if needed:

````
class Calculator extends Component {
    state = { 
        total: 0
     }

    clearTotal = () => {
        this.setState({total : 0})
    }

    inputNumber = (id) => {
        let total = this.state.total;
        let concat = total === 0 ? this.returnNumber(id) : Number("" + total + this.returnNumber(id));
        this.setState({total : concat})
        console.log(this.returnNumber(id))
    }

    render() { 
        let c = this.getClasses();
        return ( 
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="container w-25 h-100" >
                <div className="align-items-center">
                <span id="display">{this.state.total}</span>
                <div className="row">
                    <button className={c + 'danger col-6'} id="clear" onClick={this.clearTotal}>AC</button>
                    <button className={c + 'light col'} id="divide">/</button>
                    <button className={c + 'light col'} id="multiply">*</button>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <button className={c + 'secondary col'} id="seven" onClick={() => this.inputNumber(this.id)}>7</button>
                    <button className={c + 'secondary col'} id="eight">8</button>
                    <button className={c + 'secondary col'} id="nine">9</button>
                    <button className={c + 'light col'} id="subtract">-</button>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <button className={c + 'secondary col'} id="four">4</button>
                    <button className={c + 'secondary col'} id="five">5</button>
                    <button className={c + 'secondary col'} id="six">6</button>
                    <button className={c + 'light col'} id="add">+</button>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-9">
                        <div className="row">
                        <button className={c + 'secondary col'} id="three">3</button>
                        <button className={c + 'secondary col'} id="two">2</button>
                        <button className={c + 'secondary col'} id="one">1</button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                        <button className={c + 'secondary col-8'} id="zero">0</button>
                        <button className={c + 'secondary col'} id="decimal">.</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-3">
                        <button className={c + 'info h-100 w-100 col-12'} id="equals">=</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </React.Fragment> );
    }

    getClasses() {
        let b = "border border-dark btn btn-";
        return b
    }

    returnNumber(name) {
        let symbols = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
        let names = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];
        let index = names.indexOf(name);
        return symbols[index];
    }

}
 
export default Calculator;```
````

Comment: `this` is not what you think it is. That's not how JS works.

Comment: JMadelaine I assumed it wouldn't work since I'm using classes/React, the only reason why I put ```this``` is because I had seen someone suggesting it in a different context in Stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40134104/how-to-pass-the-button-value-into-my-onclick-event-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button className={c + 'secondary col'} id="seven" onClick={this.inputNumber}>7</button>
```

You can write your event handler this way

Here is the event handler:

```
inputNumber = (e) => {
        const id = e.target.id; // get id from the event target
        let total = this.state.total;
        let concat = total === 0 ? this.returnNumber(id) : Number("" + total + this.returnNumber(id));
        this.setState({total : concat})
        console.log(this.returnNumber(id))
}
```

Or

```
<button className={c + 'secondary col'} id="seven" onClick={(e) => this.inputNumber(e.target.id)}>7</button>
```

You can write your event handler this way

Here is the event handler:

```
inputNumber = (id) => {
        let total = this.state.total;
        let concat = total === 0 ? this.returnNumber(id) : Number("" + total + this.returnNumber(id));
        this.setState({total : concat})
        console.log(this.returnNumber(id))
}
```

Please read Reactjs Documentation, https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: Welcome. Could you please accept this as correct answer, if you feel so.